# (AWS/EC2/EBS) set “Delete on Termination” to true, delete instance completely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i cannot remove my last instance on amazon once i click terminate another instance get created for it self, i found that the option “Delete on Termination” is false i should turn it on, okay i have setup amazon cli and i changed “Delete on Termination” to true then i tried to terminate the instance but again new instance get created even the delete on termination is true, i realized that delete on termination whether true or false amazon ec2 still create new instance for itself.

how to delete this instance completely without creating another instance?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using Amazon EC2 **Auto Scaling**, which monitors the health of instances and launches replacements if they fail.

You should **delete your Auto Scaling group**. This will then terminate the EC2 instances that were launched via Auto Scaling.